# How do you make and edit ASUS BIOS Capsule files? How do you mod ASUS BIOS Capsule file dates?

Tags: bios, asus, flashing

ASUS BIOS files come packaged in capsule files with the extension .cap. I also have a .310 file that can be read like a capsule file and used to flash a BIOS as such.

My goal is to change the "date" of the file.

thanks! :)

I understand the issue with wrongly tampering with a BIOS file, which could brick the computer. Apparently, its quite easy to brick a BIOS, so its not the best thing to try on a live motherboard. Looking for advanced answers.

Comment: which date? created? modified? accessed? What do you hope to achieve by modifying the date of the file?

Comment: Hi, the date seems to be used as a security feature/check to prevent downgrading the BIOS. I've modded an official BIOS file (to unlock a severely limited BIOS) but could not flash it because of this reason. Also, more generally, an inability to flash a BIOS file with an older version date seems to be problematic in the case flashing to a new version leads to problems that an average user wants to reverse.

Please help!

Comment: oh, so it's some sort of date INSIDE the file, not the metadata OF the file

Comment: Please edit the question whenever adding further details.